# IIS performance improve

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Currently:

I have a ASP NET project, which utilises several ASHX.
it runs barely acceptable with daily 50000 login api calls(and each login comes diff amount of other API calls)

but now it takes >1min with daily 150,000 login api calls.

to t/shoot the problem, these thing I done on 1 of the API with sproc call which only retrieve data:

1) I run it in another brand new instance, in local-machine, it runs less than 100milisec; current web-instance runs > 1min

2) I run the sproc alone in SSMS, it take < 1sec; current web-instance runs > 1min

3) I did local parameter assignment on that particular sproc, to prevent parameter sniffing and re-built and re-exec, same result.

4) the part the serialize the Json(newtonsoft) uses static, also very fast, less than 1 sec.

I ran "http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/" and indeed very slow; but I am not sure why it's slow.

I tried to use "DebugView" ("https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896647.aspx"), since it can write plenty log without file-locking, but not sure how to put it works for web application.

**Anyway/ tool to capture the independent begin_request & end_request time externally and accurately?** (I tried to put the time span in Global.asax, but get some null parameters sometimes) Best if anyone has the idea to pinpoint the part that caused it.

sample timespan test:

```
private string single_detail(HttpContext context)
    {
        PlayDetailApiResult o = new PlayDetailApiResult
        {
             ...
        };

        string json = generateJsonFromObj(o); // init default

        try
        {

            {
                {
                    long current = 0;
                    DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
                    // call sp
                    int ret = plmainsql.getPracticeQualificationTimeLeft(...);

                    DateTime dtEnd = DateTime.Now;

                    TimeSpan ts = dtEnd - dtStart;
                    LoggingHelper.GetInstance().Debug("single_detail getPracticeQualificationTimeLeft's duration(ms): " + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

                    if (ret != 0)
                    {
                        o.Code = ...;

                    }
                }

                DateTime dtStart_1 = DateTime.Now;
                json = generateJsonFromObj(o);
                DateTime dtEnd_1 = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan ts_1 = dtEnd_1 - dtStart_1;
                LoggingHelper.GetInstance().Debug("single_detail generateJsonFromObj's duration(ms): " + ts_1.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingHelper.GetInstance().Debug("single_detail : " + ex.Message + "|" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return json;
    }
```

most of the result:

**2015-03-04 18:45:29,263 [163] DEBUG LoggingHelper single_detail getPracticeQualificationTimeLeft's duration(ms): 5.8594**

**2015-03-04 18:45:29,264 [163] DEBUG LoggingHelper single_detail generateJsonFromObj's duration(ms): 0**

these thing I noted.

1) computer's  processor usage and memory usage: memory is at 70%, which i think still is not peak

2) check if Gzip compression is enabled : my json runs on mobile (iOS/Android/WM); some code changes needed, and not tested to prevent any compress-decompress issue; as compression also increase CPU usage at the same time

Comment: Profiler?   Add lines to your .net code to check the time before and after the call?

Comment: You need to use a profiler to pinpoint where your bottleneck is, and focus in on that. I have had great luck using the [Red Gate ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) previously. I have no affiliation with Red Gate - I just have had great experiences with that product.

Comment: @TabAlleman: sql profiler? it runs on SSMS very fast;

Comment: @G_P: can it profiling on current running ASP web project? a bit costly though.

Comment: Profiler will tell you how fast it ran when your app calls it.

Comment: @TabAlleman : timespan added, but it takes milisec as well. thats' why I am totally stuck

Comment: Sounds like that's not the bottleneck then.   Try adding more time-checks in different places until you find the bottleneck.

Comment: I believe there is a free 14 day trial for the tool. This tool has paid for itself many times over in the past several years of my career, but try it out for free and see if it works for you.

Comment: @TabAlleman : sample code added above. Think so, no choice but have to add more. Thanks anyway

Comment: @G_P : thanks for the recommendation. will test on it, though a bit daunty to  runs  trial software on production

Comment: Depending on your license level of Visual Studio, you could also take a look at [the built in ASP.NET profiler options and load testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504817.aspx) and try to recreate the problem outside of production.

Comment: @G_P : haha, only pro I use, but that one needs "Visual Studio Ultimate". Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can also try miniprofiler. It is very easy to use and displays the execution time for every step or function you want to monitor.

Check out http://miniprofiler.com/